# how to sort String array Number and bind in array list in android

Tags: java, android

```
 List<String> list2 =new ArrayList<String>();
 int iArr[] = new int[ja.length()];//{"846001","846005","846000","846002","846009"}
 Arrays.sort(iArr);
 for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
      _jobject = ja.getJSONObject(i);
      iArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(_jobject.getString("Pincode"));
 }
 for(int k=0;k<iArr.length;k++) {
     list2.add(String.valueOf(iArr[k]));
 }
```

I want to sort and bind it in Array list. I want

> {"846000", "846001", "846002" ,"846005", "846009"}

but its not sorting according to given logic please suggest me where am doing wrong.

Comment: So first you sort `iArr` and then you manipulate the array in `for` loop and expect it to still be sorted?

Comment: **{"846001","846005","846000","846002","846009"}** is these your JSON ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are sorting the array before manipulating it. You should move `Arrays.sort(iArr)` to after the `for` loop.

```
List<String> list2 =new ArrayList<String>();
int iArr[] = new int[ja.length()];//{"846001","846005","846000","846002","846009"}

for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
    _jobject = ja.getJSONObject(i);
    iArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(_jobject.getString("Pincode"));
}
Arrays.sort(iArr);
for(int k=0;k<iArr.length;k++) {
    list2.add(String.valueOf(iArr[k]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The values are accessed as String so convert it to Integers and then sort it. As of now you are sorting it before you populate it properly.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
      _jobject = ja.getJSONObject(i);
      iArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(_jobject.getString("Pincode"));
 }
 Arrays.sort(iArr);
 for(int k=0;k<iArr.length;k++) {
     list2.add(String.valueOf(iArr[k]));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's simulate how your given logic will be executed when it comes to the processor.

Line 1: initialized an empty string type ArrayList

Line 2: initialized an empty int array, with the length of ja.length() long

Line 3: you sort the empty int array

Line 4 to line 7: assign Pincode to your int array sequentially from the json

We have no idea what those json object stored, but apparently they are not sorted. When they get copied to your int array, the int are not sorted as well.

Move line 3 after the line 4 to 7 for loop should do the job. You should sort the array when there is some element inside. Sort an empty has no effect.